# Concatenate Multiple String Fields and Convert to Date field using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, field-calculator, date

I'm Working in Model builder using the calculate value tool.  I have three columns - SignatureDay, SignatureMonth, SignatureYear - All three are string data types and all consist of just numbers for characters.  I can combine most values easily into a single field and then convert that field into a date.  My problem is that some values will not convert.

For instance:

```
SignatureDay   SignatureMonth    SignatureYear       Convert                SubmitDate
01                 05                 2014           20140105                1/5/2014
05                 05                 2014           20140505                5/5/2014
1                   5                 2014           201415
```

The code used to give me the values in the field

```
"Convert" = "{}{}{}".format(!SignatureYear!,!SignatureMonth!, !SignatureDay!)
```

for some reason the values with single digits and no zeroes in front, will not participate in the final output to a date type in the field "SubmitDate".

I've tried going through with the .replace() function but this table is dynamic and does not always have the same values.
So -

```
!SignatureDay!.replace('1', '01').replace('2', '02')
```

....etc   does not work, I would assume because all values 1-31(for every day possible) may not exist.  Also has to be a better way than repeating that 31 times.  I'm thinking there is an loop or something that could be run?

I'm a little lost on this one, my python experience is very limited as is my programming experience in general.

Comment: try using `!SignatureDay!.zfill(2)`.  That will pad single digits with a zero at the beginning.  [zfill](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm) is a python string method.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do replace. You just need to modify the format string.

```
"Convert" = "{}{:02d}{:02d}".format(!SignatureYear!,!SignatureMonth!, !SignatureDay!)
```

Comment: This did not work received an error.
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: "{}{:02d}{:02d}".format(u"2012",u"9", u"13") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'unicode'

Failed to execute (Combine Fields).

Comment: OK.  These are strings, not numbers.  Then use the zfill.  If these were numbers the code I posted would work, i.e.:   "Convert" = "{}{:02d}{:02d}".format(!SignatureYear!,float(!SignatureMonth!),float( !SignatureDay!))